# Is it possible to use the UI components of a SmartGWT web app in another one

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Is it possible to use the UI components of a SmartGWT web app in another one? In other words, can the GWT web application (both client & server side) to be module of the complex GWT web application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inherit a module in another module:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules

You can also compile your module to jar and distribute it.

If you use Maven: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html

Answer (score 0):

As Peter pointed out, GWT's unit of reuse across applications is module (represented by `xyz.gwt.xml`). Just make sure that the modules you want to reuse do no have entry-point declarations in their `.gwt.xml` file, otherwise entry points of both the modules will be called at startup.

If you are starting with a running application, it will be a good idea to first split it into two or more modules, identifying which modules have reusable functions and which are application specific. Then include only one or more reusable modules in other applications.